# List of list of list to data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr

I have a really complicated data type and i'd like to transform it to a data frame.

I'm using lapply like so to retrieve translations from an API like so:

```
localisedDestinationName <-lapply(uniqueLocationId[100:200], localisedDestinationNameForGivenLang)
```

Which returns data in the following structure:

```
List: localisedDestinationName            Type: List [101]                   
      [[1]]                                      list[9]
          id                                       character [1]
          type                                     character [1]
          name                                     character [1]
          source                                   list [2]
          position                                 list [2]
          categories                               character [2]
          localized Names                          list [2x3]
          status                                   character[1]
          status2                                  character[1]
      [[2]] etc....
```

I had been using `localisedDestinationNameDf <- ldply(localisedDestinationName, data.frame)`

However, now im getting the error

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2, 0
```

Perhaps, someone changed the API slightly where i pull the data from.

Does anyone know how to fix this or a different method to unlist?

I've already tried unlist, however, this doesn't retain the structure.

Desired outcome:

I want to un-nest the list to become a column with rows as values. E.g.

```
id type name source position categories.....
123 A    ABC  Y       1          C
345 B    XYZ  Z       2          D
```

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of your data and your expected output.

Comment: Try `tidyr::unnest` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.0/topics/unnest